# Parse 850 file of two separate accounts of one client Using single Trading Partner ID

Tags: edi, x12

We have one client **having two account numbers and single trading partner id**. Now 
the client sends PO(s) through VAN (Value added Network),

```
My Question: Is there any way to identify for which 
account number's PO is received?
```

Our Van process is identifying the PO on the basis of Trading Partner ID.
We need to sort the PO(s) according to account number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The N104 would be a good way to do it.  Most of the time, the N104 would designate store location, which you would cross-reference in your application to your account number.

A REF02 could also work, but the N104 was really made for this.

Answer (score 0):

yes, that can be problematic.
check andrew's answer for this, maybe other options:
- GS02 (sender)
- I one had to check the items numbers to find out the right accountID.
Check why the edi-partner has 2 accounts. This often gives a good clue on how to handle this.
 
And check if it is still needed ;-))